# Writing to file

Tags: java, java-io, filewriter

I am writing to a file for the first time, but the text on the file comes out completely wrong. Instead of numbers (which it is supposed to print), it prints unrecognizable characters. I can't seem to understand why this is happening? (in my code the print statement is inside a for loop, but this is the "shell" around the loop)

Is there a logical explanation for this?

```
try {
 FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("newFile.txt", true);
 outFile.write(number);
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Character encoding is unspecified. You should specify the character encoding.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: You can't do that with `FileWriter` - just one reason to avoid it :(

Comment: Scanner doesn't write anything anywhere, and there is no Scanner in your code. Don't introduce irrelevancies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling [`Writer.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-int-):

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.

My guess is that's *not* what you want to do. If you want to write the text representation of a number, you need to do that explicitly:

```
outFile.write(String.valueOf(number));
```

(Personally I'd recommend using `OutputStreamWriter` wrapped around a `FIleOutputStream`, as then you can - and should - specify an encoding. `FileWriter` *always* uses the platform default encoding.)

Comment: Thank you, that worked :)! I will read up on OutputStreamWriter also, if this may be a better solution.